# Can I adjust or repair this ventilation setting dial which won't stay in place?

Tags: subaru, dashboard, impreza, climate-control, vents

I have a 2012 Subaru Impreza. The knob which sets where the vents are directed refuses to stay in the leftmost setting (which directs air to the upper vents only). It can be turned that far manually but refuses to click into place and sits in an intermediate position instead. I can feel some moderate extra resistance when trying to get it into position.

Position it is supposed to stay in:

[image]

Where it actually sits if I don't hold it:

[image]

Position of the next setting, just for reference:

[image]

Is there any way to repair or adjust this?

Comment: time for a replacement.

Comment: @Moab is the doable / worth it as a DIY?

Comment: You can remove the control panel from the dash, and take it apart. You'll find lots of small parts and springs, and the plastic structure will have embrittled with age, or may have broken. It might be fixable, but it'll be a lot of time to do and the results will be far from certain. Those who've attempted this sort of repair (like Moab, and me) tend to value time a bit more than money, and will instead find a replacement panel from the dealer or a wrecking yard.